# Configuring the GPO: Computer and User Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, group-policy, domain-controller

What is the difference between the two configuration?
When to use or configure these configuration in a AD Domain?
Does the individual affect each other?
What is the best practice when configuring these GPO settings.
and to configure the User Configuration, you need to have the user account in the AD and to configure the Computer Configuration, you need to have the Computer Account? or to configure the two configuration, you need these two accounts?

Thank you for your answers and thanks in advance. Have a Great Day Ahead.
Sorry for many question, but those are interrelated. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Server Fault! It's not entirely clear what your asking here, or what problem you are having. It sounds like you are not entirely sure yourself about what your asking - before asking questions, read up on Group Policy and what it encompasses: [Technet: Group Policy for beginners](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, the user policies affect users (when they log in), and computer policies affect computers.  They have different settings, though they are applied the same way.  There isn't really much more to be said about this.  Use options in whichever one expresses your intention.  You don't necessarily need to configure both of them, though you generally would.

Comment: Fun fact - user policies can apply to computers if loopback processing is enabled. But, of course, that's an exception for things like labs and remote desktop session hosts.

Comment: To be technically correct, user configuration settings apply to user objects and the use of loopback policy processing allows the user configuration settings configured in GPO's applied to computer objects to apply to users logging on to those computers. (That sounded more complicated then it really is) - (@MDMarra: this comment is for the benefit of those who may not have as sound a grasp on Group Policy application. I know you don't need my expanded explanation).